# How to install couchDB on a media temple server?

Tags: installation, couchdb

The biggest issues im running into starting a project with CouchDB is the nightmare involved in getting it up and running.

Any tips for getting couchDB up on a media temple server or any server really?

Comment: Is it a standard distro? What problems are you getting?

Comment: Far more info is needed to solve this problem. What issues are you running into? That is, what error messages are you getting, and why won't it install?

Comment: not programming related.

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what a media template server is but I think it is a pretty standard Linux server (centos?).  The best option at the moment is to compile CouchDB from the latest source in SVN.

You will need to log onto your server using ssh then follow the instructions at:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_RHEL5

I know this says it is for RHEL5 but will work exactly the same for a recent version of Centos. If you need instructions for a different os try:
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installation

Answer (score 0):

MediaTemple uses a modified version of CentOS. But don't try the official RHEL documentation to install - It is broken because the Spidermonkey libs wont work.

Try this. I just intalled Couch on MediaTemple 10 minutes ago -
[Install CouchDB on CentOS](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/install-couch-db/)

Answer (score 0):

The "Install" link above does not work anymore.
However - successfully installed CouchDB on MediaTemple and 1und1 following step1 **here**:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/06/install-couch-db/

When you are in a virtual host environment:
Make sure you provide the path to your vhost in /etc/couchdb/local.ini

It is described in the .ini file.